# Devise and migration from MongoDB to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to migrate from MongoDB to PosgreSQL.
I uses this instruction: https://gist.github.com/kagemusha/1504633

But I have problem with Devise. I have full working authentication system.
I don't have any migration files, db schema etc.

What is the best way to migrate from MongoDB (I used Mongoid) to PostgreSQL in Devise? How to create proper `dbschema.rb` for current working devise authentication or migration files?

Comment: probably you need to create all migration i mean tables with take care of Foreign key, association of models. because mongoDB is schema less   database, postgres is not , so you need to add migration manually according to your models. Little complex task while migrate mongoDB to Postgres.

Comment: in the point of `make migrations and put fields there` you can just add the table for authentications